# What is the equivalent of & in ObjC?

Tags: c++, objective-c

It is really late. I would appreciate if you can tell me what is the Objective-C equivalent of C++'s:

```
&var1
```

in ObjC. And when I use it in C++ code I use is as var1;

I think it should be

```
**var1
```

Or am I mistaken?

EDIT:

code in c++:

```
void getHierarchy(Vector<T*> &hierarchy) {
    for(int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++) {
        childs[i]->getHierarchy(hierarchy);
    }
}
```

code in ObjC:

```
-(void) getHierarchy: (NSMutableArray **) hierarchy {
    [*hierarchy addObject:self];
    for (T *child in [self childs]) {
        [child getHierarchy:*hierarchy];
    }
}
```

Comment: `&var1` in what language?  If you're coming from a `C`-based language, the equivalent of `&var1` in `Objective-C` is probably `&var1`.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C.  Pointer stuff still works pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. That `&` from C++ indicates a [reference type](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) and has a specific meaning about creating essentially a different name for the same variable, and lets you pass things like integers into functions and allows the callee to modify the caller's version directly.

ObjC doesn't allow this exact semantic. Generally you want to fall back to the traditional C way of passing by reference, which is to use a pointer. The way you'd write that traversal method in ObjC is something like this-- you'd pass in an array that you created elsewhere and it would populate it.

```
- (void)addToHierarchy:(NSMutableArray *)hierarchy
{
    [hierarchy addObject:self];
    for (T * child in [self children]) {
        [child addToHierarchy:hierarchy];
    }
}
```

Comment: So the code I posted should work correctly then? Or should I only use one * not two **.

Comment: @MartiMarkov: Not really. Your method is set up to take a pointer-to-a-pointer (two `**`), but in your recursive case you're dereferencing it and thus passing along only a pointer to the object, so the compiler won't like that. Outside that, it could work, but is not idiomatic. The external called would need to create a mutable array and then pass in the address of its pointer, which is unnecessary. The version I posted should do the same thing and is probably a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

One example is worth thousands words...

```
    NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
if (!result && error) {
    NSLog(@"DAO :: banks --> %@", error);
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of C's `&` in objective-C is still `&` and has exactly the same behavior.